# mongodb aggregation: inverse the object relationship?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the feeling this is a beginner's question, but could not find the answer yet.
I have a single collection `countries` with a property `languages` containing an array of languages.

E.g.

```
[
  { name: "CH",  languages: ["de","fr","it","rm"]},
  { name: "FR",  languages: ["fr"]},
  { name: "DE",  languages: ["de"]},
  { name: "AT",  languages: ["de"]},
]
```

Can I use an aggregation to group by languages, so that I get a collection of unique languages, with an array of the countries where that language is spoken?
E.g.

```
[
  { language: "de", countries: ["CH","DE","AT"] },
  { language: "fr", countries: ["CH","FR"] },
  { language: "it", countries: ["CH"] },
  { language: "rm", countries: ["CH"] },
]
```

Comment: Sure. `$unwind` `languages` and then `$group` on them `$push`ing the `name` into `countries`.  Will be an expensive operation if you're doing it on the full collection and it is of any reasonable size. Would even fail if it got too large

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve it by using $unwind and $group property

```
 db.countries.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$languages" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$languages",
      countries: { $addToSet: "$name" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      language: "$_id",
      countries: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Above query will give you exact result what you are expecting.

Comment: thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Bonus: what if the countries object contains name, languages but also other properties like population; and I indeed want to group by language but include the complete country object (with or without language)?

Comment: `$$ROOT` rather than `$name` in `$addToSet`